# ListItems only show after window is resized

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, listviewitem, itemssource

I create a window from PowerShell that contains a ListView. The ListView gets its items from ItemsSource with binding. The list gets filled without problem, but when all is done, the listviewitems are not shown. They are only shown when I resize the window.

Same goes if I run again, any new items are only shown after I resize the window.

XAML:

```xml
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Name="Lv1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="N" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="I" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastWriteTime}" Width="150"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

PowerShell, I have tried with PSCustomObject, PSObject, hashtable, but same result:

```bsh
$Something = { param( $syncHash )
# Gather stuff in $t
$syncHash.DataContext[4].Add( [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $t.Name; LastWriteTime = $t.LastWriteTime } )
}

$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$syncHash.Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( ( New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader ( [xml]( Get-Content .\tt.xml ) ) ) )
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Bindings = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Lv1Source = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]
$Lv2Source = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]
0.0, 0.0, "", 0.0, $Lv1Source, $Lv2Source | foreach { $syncHash.DataContext.Add( $_ ) }
$syncHash.Button.Add_Click( {
    ( [powershell]::Create().AddScript( $Something ).AddArgument( $syncHash ) ).BeginInvoke()
} )
$syncHash.Window.DataContext = $syncHash.DataContext
0..( $syncHash.DataContext.Count - 1 ) | foreach { [void]$Bindings.Add( ( New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -ArgumentList "[$_]" ) ) }
$Bindings | foreach { $_.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::OneWay }

[void][System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding( $syncHash.Lv1, [System.Windows.Controls.ListView]::ItemsSourceProperty, $Bindings[4] )
[void][System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding( $syncHash.Lv2, [System.Windows.Controls.ListView]::ItemsSourceProperty, $Bindings[5] )

$syncHash.DataContext[4].Add( [pscustomobject]@{Name=$t.Name;LastWriteTime=$t.LastWriteTime } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem thanks to the last post [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/27b807c2-055e-4d00-bce7-116fa3a783d2/wpf-listview-and-progressbar-how-to-update-from-a-runspace), "When calling between runspaces we need to use the 'Dispatcher'".

In conclusion, the DataContext is updated through the syncHash, but in the scriptblock for the button-click, I need to use:

```bsh
$syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke( [action] {
$syncHash.Lv1.Items.Refresh()
$syncHash.DataContext[5].Add( [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $syncHash.h[$syncHash.ti] ; LastWriteTime = ( Get-Date ) } )
} )
```